# Positioning the OverlayPanel of PrimeFaces

Tags: primefaces, position, overlay, panel

Can you give me the key/values which fix an `overlayPanel` position? I want to fix it in the middle, but I can't figure it out. I have this example:

```
<p:overlayPanel id="overlayPanelSearch" for="searchButton" my="top" at="bottom">
```

Answer (score 14):

This is how I understand it. 
"my" is the overlay panel box. 
"at" is the commandButton.

```
<p:commandButton id="chartBtn" type="button" />  
<p:overlayPanel id="chartPanel" for="chartBtn" my="right top" at="right bottom">  
  ...
</p:overlayPanel>
```

So the above reads: "Connect the right top of the overlay panel with the right bottom of the command button"

Comment: Your last sentence explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 5):

Use the following attributes of overlayPanel:

```
for - Identifier of the target component to show the panel
my  - Position of the panel relative to the target (ex: my="left top")
at  - Position of the target relative to the panel (ex: at="left bottom")
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me:  <p:overlayPanel my="right bottom" at="right top" for=":showImage" hideEffect="fade" dynamic="true" widgetVar="carDialog">
                <p:outputPanel id="pictureDetail">                 
                    <p:graphicImage   value="#{graphicImageStore.streamedImageById}" rendered="#{graphicImageStore.hasImage(vmsVehicleActionBean.selected)}">
                        <f:param name="id" id="selected" value="#{vmsVehicleActionBean.selected}" />
                    </p:graphicImage> 
                </p:outputPanel>  
            </p:overlayPanel>

Comment: @user1667910, initiate a new post

Answer (score 2):

I think the documentation was false to describe how to use it.
It was described to use something like 'top left'.

Try to use **my="left top" at="left bottom"** and **it works fine!**

Hope this can help you..

Answer (score 0):

To move it to the middle simply use `middle`.

Even though the [documentation](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/7_0/#/components/overlaypanel?id=positioning) just mentions `right, left, top, middle` you can in addition use `middle` on the x-axis and the y-axis.

Example:

```
<p:overlayPanel id="overlay" my="center top" at="right center">
```

This feature might have been added later on because of this request:
https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=45084